# Using WebRTC to upload the Image captured from webcam to server

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am doing a demo project because I'm practically new to coding, and now I encountered some problems. Basically my project is about smart attendance where students will need to submit their selfie taken on a phone to the server. This project uses HTML and CSS and Js. I'm using form to submit the image, with the method POST. So I refered [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) to capture image from my webcam using WebRTC. From what I read from several forum posts, the WebRTC captures the image and the image is not an image file, instead it is in base64 format. Based on several research, here's the code that does the capturing process, in JavaScript:

```js
function takepicture() {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (width && height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      data: data,
      type: 'POST'
      success: function(dataR) {}
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error:' + error.message);
      }
    });
  } else {
    clearphoto();
  }
}
```

```html
HTML Code:

<form method="POST" form class="login100-form validate-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter e-mail">
    <input class="input100" type="text" name="staff_email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
        </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
  </div>
```

I want to submit the captured photo to server but it did not submit at all. May I know what kind of problem I'm facing? I would be happy to provide more clarification. From some other posts, they use PHP which I dont really possess the knowledge of it..... Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Karthik I want to submit the picture I've taken right after I click on the 'Take Picture' button,  unfortunately the page refreshes itself and did not submit.

Comment: Check this code - https://github.com/codepo8/interaction-cam Here he is uploading to imgur, change the URL to the server where you want to upload.

Comment: @Karthik Thanks for the link. What if I want the picture to upload to the server and the server returns back the image with the recognized person in the face? I actually have the code for the server to recognize the face in an image already, I tried with another approach. Now I would like to have the same for WebRTC approach...

Comment: Just replace the code where image has uploaded to imgur with your code that submits to your server, and process the response from your server there.

Comment: @Karthik Could you please guide me a little bit on this? I would really appreciate that....

Comment: the reason this reloads is that your form tries to submit things directly. You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form
and then https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/

Comment: @PhilippHancke Thanks for the reply. Yeah but I tried with input="file" type="file" accept="*/image" , it works flawlessly....